# UI element have different color in 12 and 13 iOS

Tags: swift, ios13, ios12

I have some UI on my screens (UIButton, UISegmentControl etc) I set color for they programmatically with logic. But they are displayed differently. On IOS 12 I have default blue color, on iOS 13 all work fine.

This I use for change color for segment control:

```
func changeTitleTextColor(normalColor: UIColor, selectedColor: UIColor) {
    let normalTextColor = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: normalColor]
    let selectedTextColor = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: selectedColor]
    self.setTitleTextAttributes(normalTextColor, for: .normal)
    self.setTitleTextAttributes(selectedTextColor, for: .selected)
}
```

For UIButton I just use:

```
 func customizeBy(checked: Bool) {
    backgroundColor = checked ? Colors.MattGreen : .white
    tintColor = checked ? .white : .clear
    borderColor = checked ? .clear : Colors.PlaceholderColor
}
```

Colors its my custom struct what return UIColor:

```
  struct Colors {
    static let MattBlack = UIColor(named: "MattBlack")! 
}
```

What can be wrong?

Comment: What is the ```Colors``` class, its not a UIKit or swiftUI class.

Comment: Its my custom class with colors from assets.